# Blog errors still link to Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, blog

https://stackoverflow.blog/404-error says to report errors on “our feedback site”, which is a link to Meta Stack Overflow. And, as Shadow Wizard remarks in a comment, the same is true of the “Any feedback?” link in the footer. Should these not link to Meta Stack Exchange instead?

---

Incidentally, I found that because [Joel’s blog](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2010/04/13/stack-exchange-20/) contains a link to a [404 page on the SE blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0).

Comment: Same with the "Any feedback?" link in footer.